# Pick Up curent user in bash on a mac when running as a login hook

Tags: macos, bash

My Script currently takes the first user returned from "users" and in testing it worked fine but once i turned it into a login hook it couldn't pickup the user properly.

Is there a way to pickup the user that is logging in?

Using $USER doesnt work either

Ive tried using "/usr/bin/logname" to get the username and that only returns "root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacOS passes the username to the script as the first argument so in bash it would be stored in $1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$USER` env variable?

Comment: Works in testing but not as a login hook